# Docker: Exit code 42

Tags: docker, docker-compose, prestashop-1.7

I am running this docker compose file

https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.7.6.2/docker-compose.yml

[image]

Comment: We need more details of what your are doing or more debug info to help. Can u run a docker inspect and share the results.